# I can't show an image on a page of a vuetify project

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the folders sorted like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUtzI.png)

As you can see all the images are stored in assets folder.

In my html page I have this tag:

```
<img :src="imageLink">
```

where imageLink is a string saved as so:

```
imageLink = '/src/assets/Zucchina.jpg'
```

but I have an error cause the source is not found.
I've inspected the sources on the web page and the assets folder is not loaded.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following

**Webpack**

And the image to something like this

```
// imageLink = "@/assets/Zucchina.jpg"

<img :src="require(`${imageLink}`)" />
```

or

```
// imageName = "Zucchina.jpg"

<img :src="require(`@/assets/${imageName}`)" />
```

**Vitejs**

```
// imageName = "Zucchina.jpg"

<template>
  <img :src="getImageUrl(imageName)" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      getImageUrl(name) {
        return new URL(`/src/assets/${name}`, import.meta.url).href
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It says 'require not defined'

Comment: @FedericoRuocco, I updated my answer, try the second option

Comment: The problem is require, it seems like it doesn't exist, don't know why

Comment: @FedericoRuocco I updated my answer if you are using ViteJS instead of Webpack